# Using C++ to traverse and modify the OpenCV image, can only modify the left part, the right can not modify

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPRAR.jpg)

The left image is the original image, the right is the image processed by the harmonic mean filter, and only the left part is processed.
This is my code.

```
Mat HarmonicBlur(Mat img, int size) {
    img += 1;

    Mat imgBlur;
    img.copyTo(imgBlur);
    int radius = size / 2;
    uchar* pointImg = img.data;
    uchar* pointImageBlur = imgBlur.data;
    size_t stepImg = img.step;
    size_t stepImgBlur = imgBlur.step;
    for (int i = radius; i < img.rows - radius; i++) {
        for (int j = radius; j < img.cols - radius; j++) {
            std::vector<double> neighbors;
            for (int k = -radius; k <= radius; k++) {
                for (int l = -radius; l <= radius; l++) {
                    neighbors.push_back(double(pointImg[(i + k) * stepImg + j + l]));
                }
            }
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int m = 0; m < neighbors.size(); m++) {
                sum += 1.0 / neighbors[m];
            }
            uchar n = neighbors.size() / sum;
            pointImageBlur[i * stepImgBlur + j] = n;
        }
    }
    //normalize(imgBlur, imgBlur, 0, 255, 32);
    return imgBlur;
}
```

I tried.at traversal and pointer traversal, and the result was the same. Also try to create an image with imgBlur.crete(). The image looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfxIL.jpg)

```
Mat HarmonicBlur(Mat img, int size) {
    img += 1;

    Mat imgBlur;
    //img.copyTo(imgBlur);
    imgBlur.create(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
    int radius = size / 2;
    uchar* pointImg = img.data;
    uchar* pointImageBlur = imgBlur.data;
    size_t stepImg = img.step;
    size_t stepImgBlur = imgBlur.step;
    for (int i = radius; i < img.rows - radius; i++) {
        for (int j = radius; j < img.cols - radius; j++) {
            std::vector<double> neighbors;
            for (int k = -radius; k <= radius; k++) {
                for (int l = -radius; l <= radius; l++) {
                    neighbors.push_back(double(pointImg[(i + k) * stepImg + j + l]));
                }
            }
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int m = 0; m < neighbors.size(); m++) {
                sum += 1.0 / neighbors[m];
            }
            uchar n = neighbors.size() / sum;
            pointImageBlur[i * stepImgBlur + j] = n;
        }
    }
    //normalize(imgBlur, imgBlur, 0, 255, 32);
    return imgBlur;
}
```

Comment: Each pixel in the image actually has 3 values and you're reading it as if there is only one. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html for a tutorial for ways to loop through an image.

Comment: The reason is that there is a problem with the image I downloaded, its type is not a grayscale image, I found that its image type is 16 after printing, and I found that 16 is a very complex image type after finding the macro definition. Once I change it to grayscale, I can walk through it. Thank you